# RVM won't install on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-11.10

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm trying to install RVM.

I enter "bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)" and then press enter, and nothing happens.  It pauses for a second and then returns to the command prompt.

RVM doesn't install.  I run rmv-v and get The program 'rvm' is currently not installed.

No errors.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Jason

UPDATE: I removed the -s option from curl and now I see some messages.  Specifically:

0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

UPDATE 2: I reinstalled Git, and now when I run curl-config --ca, I get:

curl-config --ca
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

I downloaded the cacert.pem file from curl.haxx.se and created a new ca-certificates.crt file with it.

However, I'm still getting:

0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Not sure what else to try other than disabling the checking, which I'd rather not do.

Comment: What did you find when you googled `rvm ssl certificate`?

Comment: it's curl certificates, not rvm certificate, and ubuntu 11.10 should have correct certificates installed, check in `apt-...` if you can update certificates

Answer (score 1):

The SSL certificate on https://rvm.io expired.  Looks like RVM migrated to a new domain.  See: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/889